# Range trim view implementation does not work with reverse view

Tags: c++, stl, c++20, range-v3

I wrote a C++20 range view (not a range-v3 view) called `trim` that, given a range and a unary predicate, returns a new range without the front and back elements that satisfy the predicate. (The range-v3 library has such a view, but it's missing from C++20.)

Here is the implementation (this may not be optimal, but there isn't a lot of documentation on the ranges library, so this is what I could come up with given the limited resources):

```
namespace rg = std::ranges;

// -------- trim ----------

template<rg::input_range R, typename P> requires rg::view<R>
class trim_view : public rg::view_interface<trim_view<R, P>>
{
private:
    R base_ {};
    P pred_;
    mutable rg::iterator_t<R> iter_ {std::begin(base_)};
    mutable rg::iterator_t<R> end_  {std::end(base_)};
public:
    trim_view() = default;

    constexpr trim_view(R base, P pred)
        : base_(std::move(base)), pred_(std::move(pred)), iter_(std::begin(base_)), end_(std::end(base_))
    {}

    constexpr R base() const &
    {return base_;}
    constexpr R base() && 
    {return std::move(base_);}

    constexpr auto begin()
    {
        while(iter_ != std::end(base_) && pred_(*iter_)) {iter_ = std::next(iter_);} 
        while(end_ != iter_ && pred_(*std::prev(end_))) {end_ = std::prev(end_);}
        return iter_;
    }
    constexpr auto begin() const requires rg::range<const R>
    {
        while(iter_ != std::end(base_) && pred_(*iter_)) {iter_ = std::next(iter_);} 
        while(end_ != iter_ && pred_(*std::prev(end_))) {end_ = std::prev(end_);}
        return iter_;
    }
    constexpr auto begin() requires rg::random_access_range<R> && rg::sized_range<R>
    {
        while(iter_ != std::end(base_) && pred_(*iter_)) {iter_ = std::next(iter_);} 
        while(end_ != iter_ && pred_(*std::prev(end_))) {end_ = std::prev(end_);}
        return iter_;
    }
    constexpr auto begin() const requires rg::random_access_range<const R> && rg::sized_range<const R>
    {
        while(iter_ != std::end(base_) && pred_(*iter_)) {iter_ = std::next(iter_);} 
        while(end_ != iter_ && pred_(*std::prev(end_))) {end_ = std::prev(end_);}
        return iter_;
    }

    constexpr auto end()
    { return end_ ; }
    constexpr auto end() const requires rg::range<const R>
    { return end_ ; }
    constexpr auto end() requires rg::random_access_range<R> && rg::sized_range<R>
    { return end_ ; }
    constexpr auto end() const requires rg::random_access_range<const R> && rg::sized_range<const R>
    { return end_ ; }

    constexpr auto size() requires rg::sized_range<R>
    { return std::distance(iter_, end_); }    
    constexpr auto size() const requires rg::sized_range<const R>
    { return std::distance(iter_, end_); }
};

template<class R, typename P>
trim_view(R&& base, P pred)
    -> trim_view<rg::views::all_t<R>, P>;

namespace details
{
    template <typename P>
    struct trim_view_range_adaptor_closure
    {
        P pred_;
        constexpr trim_view_range_adaptor_closure(P pred)
            : pred_(pred)
        {}

        template <rg::viewable_range R>
        constexpr auto operator()(R && r) const
        {
            return trim_view(std::forward<R>(r), pred_);
        }
    } ;

    struct trim_view_range_adaptor
    {
        template<rg::viewable_range R, typename P>
        constexpr auto operator () (R && r, P pred)
        {
            return trim_view( std::forward<R>(r), pred ) ;
        }

        template <typename P>
        constexpr auto operator () (P pred)
        {
            return trim_view_range_adaptor_closure(pred);
        }   
    };

    template <rg::viewable_range R, typename P>
    constexpr auto operator | (R&& r, trim_view_range_adaptor_closure<P> const & a)
    {
        return a(std::forward<R>(r)) ;
    }
}

namespace views
{
    inline static details::trim_view_range_adaptor trim;
}
```

It works fine. I wrote some tests to make sure it's OK.

```
template <typename P>
void are_equal(std::vector<int> const & input, std::vector<int> const & output, P&& pred)
{
    std::size_t index = 0;
    for(auto  i : input | views::trim(std::forward<P>(pred)))
    {
        assert(i == output[index]);
        index++;
    }
    assert(index == output.size());
}

int main()
{
    auto is_odd = [](const int x){return x%2==1;};

    are_equal({}, {}, is_odd);
    are_equal({1}, {}, is_odd);    
    are_equal({1,3,5}, {}, is_odd);
    are_equal({2}, {2}, is_odd);
    are_equal({2,4}, {2,4}, is_odd);
    are_equal({2,3,4}, {2,3,4}, is_odd);
    are_equal({1,2,3,4}, {2,3,4}, is_odd);
    are_equal({1,1,2,3,4}, {2,3,4}, is_odd);
    are_equal({2,3,4,5}, {2,3,4}, is_odd);
    are_equal({2,3,4,5,5}, {2,3,4}, is_odd);
    are_equal({1,2,3,4,5}, {2,3,4}, is_odd);
    are_equal({1,1,2,3,4,5,5}, {2,3,4}, is_odd);
}
```

The problem is, when I apply the `views::reverse` view after trimming then it no longer works properly.

```
template <typename P>
void are_equal_reverse2(std::vector<int> const & input, std::vector<int> const & output, P&& pred)
{
    std::size_t index = 0;
    for(auto  i : input | views::trim(std::forward<P>(pred)) | rg::views::reverse)
    {
        assert(i == output[index]);
        index++;
    }
    assert(index == output.size());
}

int main()
{
    auto is_odd = [](const int x){return x%2==1;};

    // OK
    are_equal_reverse2({}, {}, is_odd);
    are_equal_reverse2({1}, {}, is_odd);
    are_equal_reverse2({1,3,5}, {}, is_odd);
    are_equal_reverse2({2}, {2}, is_odd);
    are_equal_reverse2({2,4}, {4,2}, is_odd);
    are_equal_reverse2({2,3,4}, {4,3,2}, is_odd);
    are_equal_reverse2({1,2,3,4}, {4,3,2}, is_odd);
    are_equal_reverse2({1,1,2,3,4}, {4,3,2}, is_odd);

    // fail
    are_equal_reverse2({2,3,4,5}, {4,3,2}, is_odd);
    are_equal_reverse2({2,3,4,5,5}, {4,3,2}, is_odd);
    are_equal_reverse2({1,2,3,4,5}, {4,3,2}, is_odd);
    are_equal_reverse2({1,1,2,3,4,5,5}, {4,3,2}, is_odd);
}
```

The range {2,3,4,5} becomes {2,3,4}. With reverse applied, it should become {4,3,2}. However, the result is actually {5,4,3,2}.

I expect that `views::reverse` applies `std::make_reverse_iterator()` on the begin and end iterators of the trim view. That should perform the following transformation:

```
trim_view        reverse_view (expected)      reverse_view (actual)
--------------------------------------------------------------------
2 3 4 5 _         _ 2 3 4 5                   _ 2 3 4 5
^     ^           ^     ^                     ^       ^
|     |      =>   |     |                     |       |
|     end_        rend  |                     rend    |
iter_                   rbegin                        rbegin
```

I am not sure what I am missing here. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the link to a working sample: https://wandbox.org/permlink/4iFNsqiz9Y9Bfm64

Comment: Did you test this with the range-v3 version to see if it passes the tests?

Comment: No, I did not. I compiled it with gcc 11 using the standard library ranges only.

Comment: Just wondering if this is actually an incorrect implementation, or if there's some deeper issue here. If this doesn't work with range-v3 either, that changes the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let's start with this:

```
constexpr auto begin()
{
    while(iter_ != std::end(base_) && pred_(*iter_)) {iter_ = std::next(iter_);} 
    while(end_ != iter_ && pred_(*std::prev(end_))) {end_ = std::prev(end_);}
    return iter_;
}
constexpr auto begin() const requires rg::range<const R>
{
    while(iter_ != std::end(base_) && pred_(*iter_)) {iter_ = std::next(iter_);} 
    while(end_ != iter_ && pred_(*std::prev(end_))) {end_ = std::prev(end_);}
    return iter_;
}
constexpr auto begin() requires rg::random_access_range<R> && rg::sized_range<R>
{
    while(iter_ != std::end(base_) && pred_(*iter_)) {iter_ = std::next(iter_);} 
    while(end_ != iter_ && pred_(*std::prev(end_))) {end_ = std::prev(end_);}
    return iter_;
}
constexpr auto begin() const requires rg::random_access_range<const R> && rg::sized_range<const R>
{
    while(iter_ != std::end(base_) && pred_(*iter_)) {iter_ = std::next(iter_);} 
    while(end_ != iter_ && pred_(*std::prev(end_))) {end_ = std::prev(end_);}
    return iter_;
}

constexpr auto end()
{ return end_ ; }
constexpr auto end() const requires rg::range<const R>
{ return end_ ; }
constexpr auto end() requires rg::random_access_range<R> && rg::sized_range<R>
{ return end_ ; }
constexpr auto end() const requires rg::random_access_range<const R> && rg::sized_range<const R>
{ return end_ ; }
```

All of these overloads do the exact same thing, so let's just reduce down to two:

```
constexpr auto begin() const
{
    while(iter_ != std::end(base_) && pred_(*iter_)) {iter_ = std::next(iter_);} 
    while(end_ != iter_ && pred_(*std::prev(end_))) {end_ = std::prev(end_);}
    return iter_;
}

constexpr auto end() const
{ return end_ ; }
```

Alright now. What's going on here? `begin()` will adjust both `iter_` and `end_` to be trimmed, and `end()` just returns `end_`.

That's fine and all if you do this:

```
auto trimmed = some_range | trim(some_pred);
auto b = trimmed.begin();
auto e = trimmed.end();
```

But what happens if you do this:

```
auto e = trimmed.end();
auto b = trimmed.begin();
```

`end` in this case will be `some_range.end()`, it won't be the correct end iterator for this range! You need to ensure that `begin()` and `end()` don't have any ordering dependencies between them - they always have to return the correct value.

---

Also, `trim(p)` can be reduced in its entirety to:

```
template <rg::viewable_range R, typename P>
constexpr auto operator ()(R && r, P pred)
{
    auto negated = std::not_fn(pred);
    auto f = rg::find_if(r, negated);
    auto l = rg::find_if(r | std::views::reverse, negated).base();
    return rg::subrange(f, l);
}
```

Comment: That's a good point about the dependency of begin()-end(). I guess end() is called before begin() so it is not returning the correct value. And know trim() can be implemented in terms of other views, but my purpose is to learn about the inner details of the ranges library, so that is way I wanted to implemented this way.